# assign value of one actionscript component to another (shallow copy)

Tags: actionscript, copy, shallow-copy

I have two label components in actionscript: 
label1 and label2.

I want to make it so that when the value of label1.text changes, the value of label2.text automatically changes to the same value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) to accomplish this in pure actionscript:

```
var label1 : Label = new Label();
var label2 : Label = new Label();
BindingUtils.bindProperty(label2, "text", label1, "text);
```

Essentially this is saying "set the value of label2.text to label1.text when label1.text changes". If you want to execute code when label1.text changes, you can use a [ChangeWatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/ChangeWatcher.html).

You can accomplish this in MXML too:

```
<mx:Label id="label1" text="hello, world!"/>
<mx:Label id="label2" text="{label1.text}"/>
```